# Is there a modelling notation for CSP?

Tags: go, uml, modeling

I often use sequence diagrams when modelling systems.  Right now I'm working on a problem that has a high degree of concurrency that I intend to solve using Go and it's CSP implementation.

What I need before I start coding is a modelling notation for CSP. If not CSP specifically then something that will enable me to express and explore the processes, channels and messages between them in order to compose/design the solution.

What are my options before inventing my own?

Comment: i'm not sure if this is what you had in mind because it doesn't necessarily provide any focused primitives or graphs on current operations, but I've been using http://plantuml.com/ for pretty much all modeling, it provides a lot of different models and lets you store the diagrams in code

Comment: Why do you think SDs are not suitable for this? I think they are exactly for such kind of communication visualization.

Comment: I'd say Hoare introduced both symbolic and graphical notations in CSPbook.

Comment: @ThomasKilian good question. I haven't actually explored using SD for this but I will now.